# How to apply DISTINCT clause and MIN function to WHERE statement if you are selecting all the column?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need your help. I want to show all the column on a table where I can use **DISTINCT** clause and **MIN** function.

```
--Here is a sample code that I've tried but failed to show the expected output
SELECT * FROM TABLE  
WHERE DOCUMENT_NUMBER IN ( 
                            SELECT DISTINCT DOCUMENT_NUMBER 
                              FROM TABLE

                                          ) 
and DESIRED_DUE_DATE IN (
                          SELECT MIN(DESIRED_DUE_DATE)
                            FROM TABLE
                              GROUP BY DOCUMENT_NUMBER)
order by DOCUMENT_NUMBER desc;
```

Expected output should be the **DOCUMENT_NUMBER** are all distinct or rather no duplicate and the **DESIRED_DUE_DATE** of all distinct **DOCUMENT_NUMBER** is at minimum value while showing all the column on the table.

the above code is still showing me duplicate **Document_Number**.

Answer (score 3):

It is simpler:

```
SELECT DOCUMENT_NUMBER, MIN(DESIRED_DUE_DATE) DESIRED_DUE_DATE
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY DOCUMENT_NUMBER
ORDER BY DOCUMENT_NUMBER desc;
```

`GROUP BY` returns distinct values of `DOCUMENT_NUMBER`.
If you want all the columns of the table:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM TABLE t INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DOCUMENT_NUMBER, MIN(DESIRED_DUE_DATE) DESIRED_DUE_DATE
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY DOCUMENT_NUMBER
) g on g.DOCUMENT_NUMBER = t.DOCUMENT_NUMBER AND g.DESIRED_DUE_DATE = t.DESIRED_DUE_DATE    
ORDER BY t.DOCUMENT_NUMBER desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first condition is unnecessary.

Your second would work with a correlation clause instead of `group by`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TABLE t
WHERE t.DESIRED_DUE_DATE = (SELECT MIN(t2.DESIRED_DUE_DATE)
                            FROM TABLE t2
                            WHERE t2.DOCUMENT_NUMBER = t.DOCUMENT_NUMBER
                           )
order by t.DOCUMENT_NUMBER desc;
```